# could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net

I need to keep the button in usercontrol (.ascx) file. and i have given the AsyncPostBackTrigger  controlid for the same button. but its showing "ERROR" like could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel. could any one help me?
this i have give controlid

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">



    <ContentTemplate>

   <asp:Panel ID="pnlYourAccount" runat="server" Style="display: none; height: 100%;
      margin-left: 330px; margin-top: -230px;">

   here is my design

   </asp:Panel>

   </<ContentTemplate>

   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

`

```
<Triggers>

<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn1" EventName="Click" />

</Triggers>
```

`

this Linkbutton i have kept in user control(for Top menu). while click on the menu the content should get update

```
<asp:LinkButton class="anchorstyle" ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="MenuName" />
```

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: Please Specify some Code

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: i have given the some of the code part

Comment: add Click event aspx ane cs page then use.

Comment: add `OnClick="btn1_Click` event for your linkbutton.

Comment: thakyou for ur replay. ur telling the <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger tag i have to write it in code behine?

Comment: i have added code try it.

Comment: but my updatepanel is in aspx page.and My link button in user controll

Comment: i am not able to get updatepanel id in usercontrol.

Comment: so why are you using Triggers?. remove it and then its working properly.and any problem so write comment below my answer so i know, you have any doubt about ans.

Comment: i need trigger for partial update

Answer (score 0):

in aspx page

```
<asp:LinkButton class="anchorstyle" ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="MenuName" OnClick="btn1_Click" />
```

in aspx.cs page add this event

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //write your code here
}
```

then its working properly.

Comment: yes i have removed the trigger from aspx page. now adding the through aspx.cs page.

Comment: how can i access the user controls's control(Linkbutton) in aspx page.

Comment: so are you facing any problem ?

Comment: why are you get this control. any thing else you want on linkbutton click event?

Comment: yes. i want to set the                                         AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger;

            trigger.ControlID =  "here i want to set the id of link button";

Comment: i want to assign the trigger controlid in linkbutton click event

Comment: your button in user control and you want add trigger in aspx so its not possible.

Comment: in which way i can assign the controlid?

Comment: must be use postback without postback its not possible.again and agian your question take turn.

Comment: i have did site without any post back using panel. now i want to update only this particular page while click on the menu.

Comment: Add update panel in master page. and register your user control inside update panel.